# Python Insert data from list into SQlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to insert a list with data into a .db file.
Below is the layout of the db file.

Rank is an **INTEGER**
Description is **TEXT**

[image: db layout]

I have the following Python code below and SQlite query,
I am getting the error:

```
            Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
   line 136, in DB_Entry
    top_ten.execute('INSERT INTO Top_Ten VALUES(?,?)', [range(1,11),SMH_LADDER[:10]],)
InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

Below is the python code:

```
def DB_Entry():
# Create a connection to the database.
connection = connect(database = "top_ten.db")

# Get a cursor on the database.  This allows you to execute SQL
top_ten = connection.cursor()

top_ten.execute('INSERT INTO Top_Ten VALUES(?,?)', [range(1,11),SMH_LADDER[:10]],)

# Commit the changes to the database
connection.commit()

# Close the cursor.
top_ten.close()

# Close the database connection.
connection.close()
```

I am trying to put the contents of SMH_LADDER[:10] which are strings, and a number from the range(1,11) into db, but cannot get past this error message!

Below is the format of the list SMH_LADDER[:10]
['String1', 'String2', 'String3', 'String4', 'String5', 'String6', 'String7', 'String8', 'String9', 'String10']

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just insert two lists like that. You need to create a series of INSERT statements that inserts a pair from each list, one pair at a time. You can create the pairs with `zip`, then use `executemany` to do the inserts.

```
values = zip(range(1,11), SMH_LADDER[:10])
top_ten.executemany('INSERT INTO Top_Ten VALUES(?,?)', values)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Daniel, see pastebin link, I am now getting a different error message.    

http://pastebin.com/7m1YTNX4

Comment: NOTE: Am using Tkinter

Comment: Solved my issue, thank you! You have saved me alot of pain and time.